# Nginx send requests for missing images to backend

Tags: php, nginx, fastcgi

I'm working on a website that has copies of the same images in various sizes e.g.

/images/200x100/someimage.jpg

/images/400x200/someimage.jpg

etc.

The images are served directly by Nginx and only php requests get passed to the fastcgi.

If an image can't be found I would like to pass the request to fastcgi so that I can see if we can generate a version of the image in the correct size and then return that.

I just can't get it working - if the image is missing I can get it to call the script I want (instead of just returning a 404) BUT it is just returning the source of the php script.

This is the relevant part of my conf file:

```
location ~ (^|/)\. {
              return 404;
    }

    location /imgs {
          location ~ \.php$ {return 403;}
    }

    #Static Contents
    location ~* ^.+.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp)$ {
        try_files $uri  /$uri @backend;
        add_header Pragma "public";
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        expires     1y;
        access_log  off;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    # Static Contents
    location ~* ^.+.(ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|pdf|ppt|txt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf|js|eot|woff|svg|htc)$ {
        add_header Pragma "public";
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        expires     1y;
        access_log  off;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    location / {
                # Check if a file exists, or route it to index.php.
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~\.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/dev/shm/apache-php.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }

    location @backend {
        #return 410;
        rewrite  ^(.*)$ /image.php?url=$1;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/dev/shm/apache-php.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }
```

A missing image will then pass into the `location @backend` but I can't pass the $uri to a script.

I've been through all kinds of variations what am I doing wrong? Any suggestions gratefully appreciated! Thanks.

## Update

I've got this working in another VM perfectly (I copied the backend block and images blocks into the other conf file) - the only difference is that the one that works is using Apache instead of fastcgi.

Comment: Try to add the last keyword on the rewrite in `@backend` and remove the lines after that. This should redo the whole process with a new location on image.php, catched by `location ~\.php$`

Comment: Thanks, but I think I tried that earlier when I was at work. I've been working on  the problem this evening on a different VM (on my laptop) and it works perfectly. The only difference between the two conf files is that the one that works is proxying back to Apache not fastcgi

Comment: I thought that the cache headers would only by used if the file existed and that if the try_files used backend then this would break out of that location block into the backend block. Is this incorrect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was a just a typo.

I was trying to rewrite to `/image.php` it should have been `/images.php`

The working version of the above conf file is as follows:

```
location ~ (^|/)\. {
          return 404;
}

location /imgs {
      location ~ \.php$ {return 403;}
}

#Static Contents
location ~* ^.+.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp)$ {
    try_files $uri  /$uri @backend;
    add_header Pragma "public";
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
    expires     1y;
    access_log  off;
    log_not_found off;
}

# Static Contents
location ~* ^.+.(ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|pdf|ppt|txt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf|js|eot|woff|svg|htc)$ {
    add_header Pragma "public";
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
    expires     1y;
    access_log  off;
    log_not_found off;
}

location / {
            # Check if a file exists, or route it to index.php.
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}

location ~\.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/dev/shm/apache-php.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
}

location @backend {

    rewrite  ^(.*)$ /images.php?url=$1;
}
```